# I wrote a Google Script to alert me when 3 consecutive cells in a row that jumps around are below 12,000, but it alerts me no matter what

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to write a script that finds and isolates the "A Total" row, as it jumps around throughout the day. I then want the script to acknowledge when a new value/cell populates in the "A Total" row. New cells populate 21 times a day, in the A Total row and columns D through X. If the newly populated value/cell and the previous two values/cells in the "A Total" row are all below 12000, I want that to trigger an email to me. However, this script is emailing me even when it does not need to. Any advice? Thank you!

```
function checkATotal() {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("****");

var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

var emailAddress = "***";

var alertMessage = "Two consecutive 'A Total' cells are under 12,000";



// Find the "A Total" row

var ATotalRow = -1;

for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {

if (data[row][0] === "A Total") {

ATotalRow = row;

break;

}

}



// Check the "A Total" row

if (ATotalRow >= 0 && ATotalRow < data.length && ATotalRow > 1) {

for (var col = 3; col <= 23; col++) { // Columns D through X

if (

isNumeric(data[ATotalRow][col]) &&

isNumeric(data[ATotalRow - 1][col]) &&

isNumeric(data[ATotalRow - 2][col]) &&

Number(data[ATotalRow][col]) < 12000 &&

Number(data[ATotalRow - 1][col]) < 12000 &&

Number(data[ATotalRow - 2][col]) < 12000

) {

sendEmail(emailAddress, "Alert from A Total", alertMessage);

return;

}

}

}

}



function sendEmail(recipient, subject, message) {

MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, message);

}



function isNumeric(value) {

return !isNaN(parseFloat(value)) && isFinite(value);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can adapt this to your solution:

gs:

```
function checkATotal() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 24).getValues();
  let obj = vs.reduce((a, r, i, A) => {
    if (i > a.mini && r[0] == a.flag) {
      let row = i + 2;
      r.forEach((c, j) => {
        if (j > a.minj) {
          let col = j + 1;
          let s = parseInt(A[i - 2][j]) + parseInt(A[i - 1][j]) + parseInt(A[i][j]);
          if(!isNaN(s) && s < a.min) {
            a.lessthanmin.push({row: row, column: col, sum: s})
          }
        }
      })
    }
    return a;
  }, { min:20, mini:1, minj:2, flag:"Total", pA:[], lessthanmin:[] });
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
}
```

Data:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P | Q | R | S | T | U | V | W | X |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 | COL11 | COL12 | COL13 | COL14 | COL15 | COL16 | COL17 | COL18 | COL19 | COL20 | COL21 | COL22 | COL23 | COL24 |
| 2 |  | 15 | 16 | 15 | 24 | 7 | 21 | 27 | 32 | 3 | 16 | 6 | 34 | 13 | 13 | 32 | 10 | 12 | 22 | 1 | 19 | 16 | 10 | 27 |
| 3 |  | 8 | 26 | 20 | 29 | 7 | 17 | 20 | 32 | 10 | 6 | 27 | 3 | 13 | 0 | 30 | 29 | 18 | 13 | 22 | 28 | 18 | 11 | 23 |
| 4 | Total | 2 | 10 | 14 | 0 | 18 | 6 | 23 | 17 | 19 | 27 | 6 | 20 | 18 | 3 | 22 | 30 | 15 | 33 | 16 | 34 | 13 | 27 | 26 |
| 5 |  | 20 | 22 | 9 | 21 | 8 | 6 | 11 | 29 | 31 | 4 | 5 | 25 | 30 | 2 | 21 | 2 | 17 | 32 | 17 | 27 | 6 | 18 | 4 |
| 6 |  | 9 | 7 | 28 | 12 | 7 | 17 | 13 | 21 | 10 | 20 | 6 | 20 | 20 | 17 | 4 | 29 | 14 | 11 | 28 | 33 | 6 | 2 | 17 |
| 7 | Total | 32 | 4 | 31 | 24 | 30 | 28 | 10 | 25 | 8 | 21 | 2 | 14 | 23 | 20 | 6 | 29 | 16 | 17 | 22 | 5 | 15 | 21 | 9 |
| 8 |  | 8 | 31 | 6 | 31 | 17 | 26 | 13 | 1 | 23 | 30 | 10 | 6 | 2 | 0 | 7 | 29 | 17 | 9 | 16 | 13 | 13 | 24 | 1 |
| 9 |  | 5 | 25 | 26 | 11 | 26 | 19 | 10 | 29 | 3 | 24 | 3 | 12 | 22 | 29 | 13 | 17 | 3 | 32 | 6 | 30 | 28 | 4 | 32 |
| 10 | Total | 30 | 15 | 24 | 10 | 22 | 11 | 4 | 14 | 15 | 29 | 10 | 18 | 9 | 34 | 23 | 18 | 5 | 24 | 9 | 30 | 24 | 22 | 14 |
| 11 |  | 32 | 22 | 13 | 34 | 3 | 16 | 10 | 33 | 14 | 34 | 7 | 0 | 19 | 11 | 23 | 29 | 9 | 31 | 15 | 30 | 9 | 5 | 31 |
| 12 |  | 27 | 30 | 9 | 6 | 18 | 6 | 18 | 9 | 22 | 3 | 22 | 34 | 11 | 30 | 5 | 6 | 8 | 1 | 3 | 12 | 7 | 8 | 12 |
| 13 | Total | 8 | 26 | 31 | 8 | 32 | 13 | 10 | 7 | 16 | 9 | 21 | 25 | 28 | 9 | 14 | 34 | 1 | 6 | 25 | 1 | 28 | 14 | 32 |
| 14 |  | 6 | 4 | 27 | 26 | 22 | 1 | 24 | 5 | 5 | 16 | 12 | 25 | 25 | 14 | 12 | 28 | 5 | 18 | 19 | 3 | 12 | 1 | 11 |
| 15 |  | 1 | 9 | 17 | 11 | 24 | 0 | 12 | 9 | 16 | 7 | 14 | 17 | 31 | 23 | 10 | 32 | 28 | 5 | 7 | 32 | 23 | 11 | 8 |
| 16 | Total | 32 | 9 | 16 | 9 | 25 | 16 | 20 | 29 | 23 | 33 | 33 | 30 | 20 | 24 | 19 | 2 | 4 | 26 | 14 | 2 | 32 | 27 | 7 |
| 17 |  | 18 | 2 | 20 | 32 | 34 | 10 | 1 | 28 | 24 | 11 | 15 | 29 | 16 | 14 | 1 | 28 | 15 | 7 | 0 | 34 | 3 | 1 | 7 |
| 18 |  | 20 | 24 | 2 | 13 | 28 | 3 | 0 | 18 | 24 | 27 | 30 | 9 | 11 | 13 | 24 | 5 | 13 | 26 | 31 | 22 | 4 | 16 | 10 |
| 19 | Total | 14 | 2 | 13 | 25 | 12 | 31 | 2 | 27 | 2 | 21 | 32 | 3 | 8 | 8 | 7 | 28 | 33 | 26 | 27 | 31 | 21 | 14 | 11 |
| 20 |  | 17 | 20 | 22 | 11 | 2 | 12 | 15 | 27 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 1 | 26 | 18 | 20 | 10 | 15 | 12 | 29 | 10 | 24 | 13 | 12 |
| 21 |  | 13 | 26 | 23 | 14 | 11 | 26 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 26 | 6 | 34 | 28 | 18 | 10 | 28 | 31 | 28 | 5 | 15 | 4 | 4 | 21 |
| 22 | Total | 11 | 23 | 12 | 28 | 7 | 26 | 19 | 8 | 8 | 6 | 26 | 24 | 10 | 34 | 15 | 3 | 14 | 32 | 28 | 32 | 23 | 28 | 26 |
| 23 |  | 30 | 25 | 26 | 11 | 0 | 31 | 16 | 27 | 4 | 1 | 28 | 28 | 31 | 2 | 23 | 30 | 2 | 28 | 17 | 12 | 16 | 10 | 26 |
| 24 |  | 14 | 10 | 24 | 5 | 2 | 13 | 18 | 22 | 21 | 34 | 14 | 33 | 14 | 14 | 16 | 10 | 28 | 27 | 0 | 27 | 20 | 25 | 2 |
| 25 | Total | 6 | 33 | 11 | 17 | 10 | 34 | 3 | 23 | 19 | 29 | 28 | 8 | 9 | 34 | 31 | 15 | 6 | 30 | 2 | 25 | 21 | 7 | 23 |
| 26 |  | 24 | 23 | 18 | 5 | 28 | 6 | 30 | 3 | 3 | 8 | 20 | 25 | 22 | 16 | 26 | 29 | 17 | 17 | 8 | 21 | 24 | 20 | 17 |
| 27 |  | 20 | 19 | 34 | 34 | 22 | 10 | 28 | 19 | 12 | 25 | 18 | 11 | 17 | 9 | 30 | 21 | 21 | 13 | 33 | 25 | 3 | 6 | 2 |
| 28 | Total | 33 | 2 | 10 | 21 | 10 | 30 | 23 | 12 | 14 | 19 | 13 | 15 | 9 | 22 | 31 | 30 | 18 | 13 | 0 | 12 | 7 | 26 | 31 |
| 29 |  | 1 | 14 | 13 | 31 | 16 | 6 | 26 | 34 | 7 | 20 | 30 | 33 | 11 | 13 | 33 | 8 | 24 | 22 | 8 | 9 | 32 | 13 | 0 |
| 30 |  | 6 | 17 | 22 | 32 | 25 | 27 | 13 | 4 | 28 | 6 | 6 | 17 | 23 | 20 | 34 | 3 | 10 | 18 | 34 | 9 | 12 | 21 | 1 |
| 31 | Total | 34 | 2 | 12 | 2 | 10 | 14 | 25 | 24 | 23 | 32 | 31 | 5 | 0 | 27 | 6 | 6 | 31 | 27 | 33 | 20 | 34 | 3 | 1 |
| 32 |  | 24 | 14 | 27 | 14 | 16 | 5 | 15 | 32 | 31 | 1 | 20 | 12 | 33 | 24 | 31 | 25 | 28 | 25 | 12 | 19 | 34 | 3 | 0 |
| 33 |  | 18 | 21 | 31 | 30 | 3 | 11 | 26 | 33 | 18 | 27 | 10 | 6 | 13 | 14 | 22 | 3 | 3 | 32 | 23 | 8 | 29 | 34 | 28 |
| 34 | Total | 9 | 18 | 7 | 13 | 26 | 24 | 19 | 14 | 12 | 10 | 14 | 11 | 12 | 23 | 24 | 3 | 30 | 8 | 25 | 3 | 12 | 17 | 33 |
| 35 |  | 25 | 11 | 29 | 23 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 5 | 28 | 31 | 27 | 23 | 24 | 6 | 20 | 9 | 0 | 25 | 11 | 8 | 25 | 16 | 23 |
| 36 |  | 20 | 8 | 23 | 14 | 5 | 22 | 21 | 31 | 34 | 9 | 4 | 14 | 2 | 8 | 10 | 21 | 24 | 27 | 31 | 29 | 19 | 21 | 20 |
| 37 | Total | 20 | 8 | 23 | 14 | 5 | 22 | 21 | 31 | 34 | 9 | 4 | 14 | 2 | 8 | 10 | 21 | 24 | 27 | 31 | 29 | 19 | 21 | 20 |

Execution Log:

```
Execution log
1:06:27 PM  Notice  Execution started
1:06:27 PM  Info    {"min":20,"mini":1,"minj":2,"flag":"Total","pA":[],"lessthanmin":[{"row":4,"column":15,"sum":16},{"row":7,"column":12,"sum":13},{"row":13,"column":18,"sum":18},{"row":16,"column":7,"sum":17},{"row":19,"column":8,"sum":3},{"row":25,"column":6,"sum":12},{"row":25,"column":20,"sum":19},{"row":31,"column":17,"sum":17},{"row":31,"column":24,"sum":2},{"row":37,"column":6,"sum":18}]}
1:06:29 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

- [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)